# Estimation of superexponential integral

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

I was wondering if anyone could give as precise an estimate as possible
for the integral
$$ 
\int_0^b e^{-a e^{-x^2}}\, dx,
$$
where $a$ is positive.  It is not related to any special functions as far as I can tell.
Of course, it is less than $b$ since the integrand is less than $1$, but I could use a
much more precise estimate.  Thanks.

Comment: I am curious about the context in which this problem arises, and also the required level of precision.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$f(x)=e^{-ae^{-x^2}}$$
is increasing on the interval $(0,b)$. Therefore an estimate would be 
$$\int^{b}_{0}f(0)\,dx\leq\int^{b}_{0}f(x)\,dx\leq\int^{b}_{0}f(b)\,dx$$
or in other words
$$f(0)\cdot b\leq\int^{b}_{0}f(x)\,dx\leq f(b)\cdot b$$
or 
$$e^{-a}b\leq\int^{b}_{0}f(x)\,dx\leq e^{-ae^{-b^2}}b$$